# Haskell: if-then-else conditioning problem

Tags: function, if-statement, haskell

I am fairly new to Haskell and trying to comprehend writing functions and if else conditions and everything else. I am trying to write a very basic function but I don't fully understand if-then-else usage. I have a maze that i represent as [[Char]]. And this function will simply look at the position x,y in the maze and returns if it's a valid position or not. (whether it's in the maze boundaries or not)

I have written this so far:

```
is_valid_position :: Int -> Int -> [[Char]] -> Bool

is_valid_position x y maze
        if(x < 0 || y < 0)
            then False
        if(x >= length maze || y >= length (maze!!0))
            then False
        else True
```

This gives an error because of the 'else' usage right now. What I'm trying to write in python is like this:

```
def is_valid_position(maze, pos_r, pos_c):
    if pos_r < 0 or pos_c < 0:
        return False
    if pos_r >= len(maze) or pos_c >= len(maze[0]):
        return False
    
    return True
```

How should I change my Haskell code? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if-else` expression *requires* both parts. You can nest the expressions, so something like `if c1 then a else if c2 then b else c`.

```
is_valid_position x y maze = if (x < 0 || y > 0)
                             then False
                             else if (x >= length maze | y >= length (maze !! 0)
                                  then False
                                  else True
```

However, you don't need `if-else` expression here, since you are working purely with Boolean values. You can simply use `&&` and `||`.

```
-- Instead of prohibiting any condition to be true,
-- require each negated condition to be true
is_valid_position x y maze = x >= 0
                             && y >= 0
                             && x < length maze
                             && y < length (maze !! 0)
```

Guard conditions are also an option to break it up a little bit:

```
is_valid_position x y maze | x < 0 = False
                           | y < 0 = False
                           | x >= length maze = False
                           | y >= length (maze !! 0) = False
                           | otherwise = True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's hard right now for me to think in functional programming paradigm since i used imperative languages all the time. Do you suggest any books or website that give good explanation and examples? I checked a few, right now reading Programming in Haskell by Graham Hutton.

Comment: @bibble: Side note: while the body of the definition must be indented more than the start of the line, so that it continues the same statement (`is_valid_position … = …;`), none of the other indentation here is significant, it’s just a style preference. If you’re new to Haskell and you run into trouble aligning things correctly, a simpler rule is to just put a newline and 2- or 4-space indent after each layout keyword (`do`, `where`, `of`, `let`), just like you would do after `:` in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Chepner's answer is excellent. But the "true Haskell" way of doing things would be a little bit different.

First, we define

```hs
(!!?) :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
[]     !!? _ = Nothing
(x:xs) !!? n = if n == 0
               then Just x
               else xs !!? n - 1
```

Then, we define

```hs
charAtPosition :: Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> Maybe a
charAtPosition x y maze = if x < 0 || y < 0
                          then Nothing else
                              case maze !!? x of
                                  Nothing -> Nothing
                                  Just column -> column !!? y
```

`charAtPosition x y maze` returns the character at position `x, y` if there is such a character. Otherwise, it returns 0. To check whether indices `x` and `y` are valid, we simply say

```hs
isValidPosition x y maze = isJust (charAtPosition x y maze)
```

(where `isJust` is imported from Data.Maybe).

Note that we can actually clean up `charAtPosition` using the power of monad notation. Haskell defines the following function:

```hs
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
w >>= f = case w of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just k  -> f k
```

Using `>>=`, we can thus rewrite `charAtPosition x y maze` to be

```hs
charAtPosition x y maze = if x < 0 || y < 0
                          then Nothing
                          else (maze !!? x) >>= (!!? y)
```

Another common piece of monad notation is `>>`. In this case, `>>` is defined by

```hs
(>>) :: Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe b
a >> b = case a of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just c  -> b
```

The last piece of the puzzle is the `guard` function, defined in Control.Monad. In this case, the definition is

```hs
guard :: Bool -> Maybe ()
guard bool = if bool
             then Just ()
             else Nothing
```

With the pieces of the puzzle, we can write

```hs
charAtPosition x y maze = guard (x >= 0 && y >= 0) >> (maze !!? x) >>= (!!? y)
```

We can make this slightly nicer using `do` notation to get

```hs
charAtPosition x y maze = do guard (x >= 0 && y >= 0)
                             (maze !!? x) >>= (!!? y)
```

which is the final Haskell way to write `charAtPosition`. Informally, we can read the definition of `charAtPosition x y maze` as saying: first, make sure that `x >= 0` and that `y >= 0`. Then, attempt to look up the `x`th element of `maze`. Finally, attempt to look up the `y`th element of the result.